# How to restrict access to routes at certain times in laravel

Tags: laravel

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict access to  routes-blades at certain hours or minutes within a day ?
Any documentation about this topic ?

Comment: Create a `middleware` that returns a `404` (or similar) at certain times of the day (using `Carbon`, which is included with Laravel) and protect the routes you want this to apply to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a middleware

```sh
php artisan make:middleware TimeBasedRestriction
```

Return a different response or redirect if time isn't appropriate

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TimeBasedRestriction
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // if not working hours, access forbidden
        if (!now()->isBetween('09:00:00', '16:00:00')) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Day is over, come back tomorrow'
            ], 403); // Status forbidden
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add the middleware to your route middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'restrictedToDayLight' => \App\Http\Middleware\TimeBasedRestriction::class,
    ];
```

And add it to your restricted routes in `web.php` for example

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware('restrictedToDayLight');
```